# django webpack loader setting to load css

Tags: django, webpack

It works when I set up like below. I am using [django-webpack-loader](https://github.com/ezhome/django-webpack-loader)

index.html

```
{% load render_bundle from webpack_loader %}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Jayground</title>
        {% render_bundle 'main' 'css' %}
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="react-app"></div>
        {% render_bundle 'main' 'js' %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Header.js

```
import styles from './header.css';

export default class Header extends React.Component {
    render(){
        <div className="header">
            hello
        </div>
    }
}
```

webpack.config.js (I made styles.css separately and then load css file in html separately so that className="header" works.)

```
config.plugins = config.plugins.concat([
    new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css'),
]);

config.module.rules.push(
    {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
            use: 'css-loader'
        })
    }
)
```

According to what I understood, code below should work too. If I don't separate css file by using ExtractTextWebpackPlugin, bundle js file have css information in it like this.

```
exports.push([module.i, ".header {\r\n  background-color: blue;\r\n}\r\n\r\n.extra {\r\n\tfont-size: 50;\r\n}", ""]);
```

css should be loaded properly.

Header.js

```
import styles from './header.css';

export default class Header extends React.Component {
    render(){
        <div className={styles.header}>
            hello
        </div>
    }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
config.module.rules.push(
    {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
    }
)
```

Do I miss something to work properly?